# Fixing a boot loop?

Tags: firefox-os

Following directions found here: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/01/upgrading-your-zte-open-to-firefox-1-1-or-1-2-fastboot-enabled/comment-page-1/#comment-2157666

I entered a boot loop. Infinite looping. I read that this could be escaped by holding Vol+Up & Vol+Down then plugging in a usb drive while the battery is removed. This should bring up a button, however it did not for me.

Does anyone know how to salvage the OS from a boot loop?

Answer (score 1):

Your upgrade didn't work. Try to upgrade again by following these instructions (they worked for me):

```
adb reboot bootloader
```

Wait for your phone to reboot, and while it is rebooting, execute those commands:

```
fastboot flash boot boot.img
fastboot flash userdata userdata.img
fastboot flash system system.img
fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
fastboot erase cache
fastboot reboot
```

If it's still not working, I guess your choice will be to downgrade to 1.1. You also need to be sure that it's a ZTE Open bought on eBay, as this build isn't for others like the one people can buy at Movistar.

Comment: Where are the correct instructions to downgrade?  Sorry for the noobie question...

Comment: You can try to install 1.1 without fastboot to get back to the point you were before. The instructions are at https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/12/upgrading-your-zte-open-to-firefox-os-1-1/ .

Comment: Reddit/r/FirefoxOS has (unfortunately) been a better resource than mozilla. Between stackexchange and reddit I was able to get this unbricked and upgraded

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment. What seems to work is to downgrade, try again. Repeating the process a few times. Not sure why. I have two ebay US ZTE Opens and this was the case on both phones.

Comment: Where are the correct instructions to downgrade? Sorry for the noobie question...